# Binding Special Keys

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike

Currently I have three separate .cfg files for CS:GO and two default "buys" I execute when playing. On a Razer Blackwidow Ultimate there are 5 "special keys" labelled M1-5 down the left of the keyboard.

I want to bind these keys in game to execute commands automatically however I'm unsure as how to reference these keys. I will add more info if required but this is a basic question.

*Example Code* "bind +M1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have pretty much the same keyboard, and what you can do is to use the Razer synapse software to create a buy macro that you link to those keys. The macro can be set to be executed as if you were to press, for example: B 4 2 for AK or M4. Or, alternatively, you can simply bind those 5 keys to something you never will use otherwise, like pgup, pgdown and so on. Here is two screenshots showing my configuration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/92mcf.png

You can read more about it here: http://www.razerzone.com/synapse/

In short, those 5 keys remain "ghosts" on your keyboard until you give them a function trough your software. You are also able to create new macros on-the-fly by using a set key combination, but this can be clunky, and also easy to screw up.

Comment: Thank you for the post. I was aware of the macro feature but wasn't sure I could apply it in game. I will look into this, and will confirm it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `MOUSE(x)`, x being the number of the button. Left click is 1, right click is 2, middle is 3 and so on. For example, as far as I'm aware the button you are after for M1 is `MOUSE4`.

Comment: Hello, I am a little unsure. I will double check but believe mouse 4/5 are the side buttons on my Chroma (as they're already used) but definitely will check!

Comment: Okay, I've got to go now, let me know if it works!